# How to cascade persist a @ManyToOne relation (TransientPropertyValueException)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a DB mapping using `hibernate`: each `Person` may only have one single `Address`, but the same address may be assigned to multiple persons (eg gamily members).

The following mapping does not work:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_address_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_addres"))
    private Address address;
}


@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String city;
    private int zip;
    private String street;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Person> persons;
}


@Transactional
public void create() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setStreet("test 1");
    address.setCity("test");
    address.setZip(123);
    person.setAddress(address);
    dao.save(person);
}
```

Result:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : Person.address -> Address
```

Why am I getting this exception, and how can I prevent it? I thought due to the cascading the address should automatically get saved?

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE})` to `private Set<Person> persons;` or change from `ALL` to `MERGE`. The problem is that you are making changes to Person and not saving them before saving Address. The Merge Cascade will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the answer given by Nicholas Robinson .. here is what's going on :

Person doesn't cascade changes to Address ... but Address does ... you then have to save the address

change

dao.save(person);

by

dao.save(address);